# Are you able to switch to lightmode in Abp Lepton X Lite Theme

Tags: abp

I am using ABP Framework Community and want to switch to Lightmode... Is this possible in the Lepton X Lite Theme or only in the Commercial one?

If yes, how can you do this?

Comment: No, LeptonX Lite does not provide you theme mode to change, you need to use LeptonX Theme if you want to change to light mode (if you are a commercial customer).

Answer (score 2):

The LeptonX you are using in the Commercial version supports this automatically. Unfortunately, this is not automatically possible in LeptonX Lite. For more information about LeptonX Lite, please see the [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/6.0/Themes/LeptonXLite/AspNetCore).